# Sencha Touch 2 Application Architecture Advice Wanted

Tags: architecture, sencha-touch, extjs

I am looking to create a web app in Sencha Touch 2 that will be used for taking short customer satisfaction surveys from users at seminar events.

I'm wondering if any of the community would be kind enough to advise what the best overall approach would be for this solution

Project Requirements:

- Simple form with contact fields, some drop down boxes and a submit
  button. (Ext.form.panel)
- Form data converted to CSV or XML format for later upload into a
  customer database Submission of CSV files to a Dropbox or Google
  Drive account as temporary storage
- Ability to use the app offline and store survey data on handset until
  data connection is present

The app may at times need to gather around 300 surveys in offline mode before being in the presence of an internet connection.

Will this be possible to build using Sencha Touch 2?
What would be the best way to tackle this project? (Use of SQLite, Ext.Ux.Exporter, possibly serverside scripts etc?)

I know this is quite a big ask on these forums, but any advice in architecting this solution would be so much appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Building forms (with Ajax requests to get and/or put your data to a server) is easy in Sencha Touch 2. You can find a lot of example on the web or in sencha doc http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/example/forms

Sencha Touch handles offline mode also : http://www.sencha.com/learn/taking-sencha-touch-apps-offline/

You should search also for "local storage" and "manifest" keywords. Also look at the solitaire demo (touchsolitaire) for local app example

I do not really understand why someone would have 300 surveys on his phone/tablet stored ? Anyway I believe a survey must not be a big object. I do not see any pb saving 300 localy.

You could use a REST architecture for your client/server and JSON messages. Your server could be in any language (Java with servlets, NodeJS for javascript server etc...). This topic is too wide to discuss it in detail. Same for Database choice.

You might be able to save your local data to a CSV file in your phone dropbox. For that you might need to use Phonegap (cordova) to access the file system of your phone (I am no expert in that topic so I might be wrong). CSV is readable by excel. To write an excel file on the phone I think it is very complicated. Some libs exist on the server side to write open office documents. You should look for that maybe.

Hope it helped ++